# fragments in MainActivity - transaction.add

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions

I'm having problem with adding a fragment to the MainActivity.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

b1 frag = new b1();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.my_layout, frag,"ECalc");
transaction.commit();
```

Error:
`The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, b1, String)`

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show something from `b1` class? the most interesting thing is to reveal its parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your `b1` class (very bad naming) extends from [`android.app.Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and not from [`support.v4.app.Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) - if your b1 class extends anything ... So change b1 to extend from support library fragment class.

Comment: Yup you were right.In future I'll avoid such naming conventions. Thanks man.